# I can't import tensorflow after updating packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, tensorflow2.0

The tensorflow has some problem after updating all packages using "conda update --all", before that update everything was working fine.

When I try to import it, the console will close and return "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)".

I don't remember the package's version before update and also cleaned whole cache with "conda clean --all".

My computer is an old laptop with windows 7 and core i5 m460 CPU, also i'm using python 3.7.7.

Also list of all packages that I'm using

```
# platform: win-64
_tflow_select=2.3.0=mkl
absl-py=0.9.0=py37_0
anaconda-client=1.7.2=py37_0
anaconda-navigator=1.9.12=py37_0
astor=0.8.0=py37_0
attrs=19.3.0=py_0
backcall=0.2.0=py_0
blas=1.0=mkl
blinker=1.4=py37_0
brotlipy=0.7.0=py37he774522_1000
ca-certificates=2020.6.24=0
cachetools=4.1.1=py_0
certifi=2020.6.20=py37_0
cffi=1.14.0=py37h7a1dbc1_0
chardet=3.0.4=py37_1003
click=7.1.2=py_0
cloudpickle=1.5.0=py_0
clyent=1.2.2=py37_1
colorama=0.4.3=py_0
conda=4.8.3=py37_0
conda-package-handling=1.6.1=py37h62dcd97_0
console_shortcut=0.1.1=4
cryptography=2.9.2=py37h7a1dbc1_0
cycler=0.10.0=py37_0
cytoolz=0.10.1=py37he774522_0
dask-core=2.22.0=py_0
decorator=4.4.2=py_0
freetype=2.10.2=hd328e21_0
gast=0.2.2=py37_0
google-auth=1.20.1=py_0
google-auth-oauthlib=0.4.1=py_2
google-pasta=0.2.0=py_0
graphviz=2.38=hfd603c8_2
grpcio=1.27.2=py37h351948d_0
h5py=2.10.0=pypi_0
hdf5=1.8.20=hac2f561_1
icc_rt=2019.0.0=h0cc432a_1
icu=58.2=ha925a31_3
idna=2.10=py_0
imageio=2.9.0=py_0
importlib-metadata=1.7.0=py37_0
importlib_metadata=1.7.0=0
intel-openmp=2019.4=245
ipython=7.17.0=py37h39e3cac_0
ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py37_0
jedi=0.17.2=py37_0
joblib=0.16.0=py_0
jpeg=9b=hb83a4c4_2
jsonschema=3.2.0=py37_1
jupyter_core=4.6.3=py37_0
keras=2.3.1=0
keras-applications=1.0.8=py_1
keras-base=2.3.1=py37_0
keras-preprocessing=1.1.0=py_1
kiwisolver=1.2.0=py37h74a9793_0
libmklml=2019.0.5=0
libopencv=3.4.2=h20b85fd_0
libpng=1.6.37=h2a8f88b_0
libprotobuf=3.12.3=h7bd577a_0
libtiff=4.1.0=h56a325e_1
lz4-c=1.9.2=h62dcd97_1
markdown=3.1.1=py37_0
matplotlib=3.2.2=0
matplotlib-base=3.2.2=py37h64f37c6_0
menuinst=1.4.16=py37he774522_1
mkl=2020.1=216
mkl-service=2.3.0=py37hb782905_0
mkl_fft=1.1.0=py37h45dec08_0
mkl_random=1.1.1=py37h47e9c7a_0
nbformat=5.0.7=py_0
networkx=2.4=py_1
numpy=1.19.1=py37h5510c5b_0
numpy-base=1.19.1=py37ha3acd2a_0
oauthlib=3.1.0=py_0
olefile=0.46=py37_0
opencv=3.4.2=py37h40b0b35_0
openssl=1.1.1g=he774522_0
opt_einsum=3.1.0=py_0
parso=0.7.0=py_0
pickleshare=0.7.5=py37_1001
pillow=7.2.0=py37hcc1f983_0
pip=20.2.1=py37_0
powershell_shortcut=0.0.1=3
progressbar2=3.51.4=pypi_0
prompt-toolkit=3.0.5=py_0
protobuf=3.12.3=py37h33f27b4_0
psutil=5.7.0=py37he774522_0
py-opencv=3.4.2=py37hc319ecb_0
pyasn1=0.4.8=py_0
pyasn1-modules=0.2.7=py_0
pycosat=0.6.3=py37he774522_0
pycparser=2.20=py_2
pydot=1.4.1=py37_0
pygments=2.6.1=py_0
pyjwt=1.7.1=py37_0
pyopenssl=19.1.0=py_1
pyparsing=2.4.7=py_0
pyqt=5.9.2=py37h6538335_2
pyrsistent=0.16.0=py37he774522_0
pysocks=1.7.1=py37_1
python=3.7.7=h81c818b_4
python-dateutil=2.8.1=py_0
python-utils=2.4.0=pypi_0
pytz=2020.1=py_0
pywavelets=1.1.1=py37he774522_0
pywin32=227=py37he774522_1
pyyaml=5.3.1=py37he774522_1
qt=5.9.7=vc14h73c81de_0
qtpy=1.9.0=py_0
requests=2.24.0=py_0
requests-oauthlib=1.3.0=py_0
rolling=0.2.0=pypi_0
rsa=4.6=py_0
ruamel_yaml=0.15.87=py37he774522_1
scikit-image=0.16.2=py37h47e9c7a_0
scikit-learn=0.23.1=py37h25d0782_0
scipy=1.5.0=py37h9439919_0
selenium=3.141.0=py37hfa6e2cd_1001
setuptools=49.3.1=py37_0
sip=4.19.8=py37h6538335_0
six=1.15.0=py_0
sqlite=3.32.3=h2a8f88b_0
tensorboard=2.2.1=pyh532a8cf_0
tensorboard-plugin-wit=1.6.0=py_0
tensorflow=2.1.0=mkl_py37ha977152_0
tensorflow-base=2.1.0=mkl_py37h230818c_0
tensorflow-estimator=2.1.0=pyhd54b08b_0
tensorflow-mkl=2.1.0=h4fcabd2_0
tensorlayer=2.2.3=pypi_0
termcolor=1.1.0=py37_1
threadpoolctl=2.1.0=pyh5ca1d4c_0
tk=8.6.10=he774522_0
toolz=0.10.0=py_0
tornado=6.0.4=py37he774522_1
tqdm=4.48.2=py_0
traitlets=4.3.3=py37_0
urllib3=1.25.10=py_0
vc=14.1=h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime=14.16.27012=hf0eaf9b_3
wcwidth=0.2.5=py_0
werkzeug=0.16.1=py_0
wheel=0.34.2=py37_0
win_inet_pton=1.1.0=py37_0
wincertstore=0.2=py37_0
wrapt=1.12.1=py37he774522_1
xmltodict=0.12.0=py_0
xz=5.2.5=h62dcd97_0
yaml=0.2.5=he774522_0
zipp=3.1.0=py_0
zlib=1.2.11=h62dcd97_4
zstd=1.4.5=h04227a9_0
```

Comment: Can you share the packages in the Conda environment?

Comment: @AMC list of packages has been added to the question

Comment: Can you share the output of `conda list` ?